# How to allow a group access for a GIT repo (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, permissions

- So I have a GIT repo hosted with Gitosis.
- I have a user called user1 and of course user root.
- user1 belongs to group 'dev'
- /var/www is owned by root, and grouped to 'dev'
- permissions for the group are rwx
- user1 has confirmed access to the git repo. I cloned it already and that works fine.

BUT, when I try to have user1 pull the repo on /var/www I get

```
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
```

So what else am I missing. The GIT repo is already a --shared repo.  For some reason I can't get this user to pull on /var/www ?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "user1 pull the repo on /var/www"? Do you `cd /var/www` and run `git pull`? Is there a reason you don't simply do a `git push` from the cloned repo as `user1`?

Comment: I'm assuming this doesn't work?

    chmod -R g+rwx /var/www/repo/.git

Comment: Yea, I SSH with user1, CD to /var/www and run git pull, then i get access denied.  The reason I don't git push is because user1 wants access to pull from the developers to the dev repo when I'm not around.

Comment: `ls -l .git/FETCH_HEAD` says ...

Comment: -rw-rwsr-- 1 root root 95 2013-04-09 14:12 .git/FETCH_HEAD
good call, so how do i change this to be root dev ?

Comment: note that the repo is housed on a different server than the one I'm pulling on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out the answer was to change the GROUP of the .git folder to that of the user.
I hadn't realized that .git/FETCH_HEAD was a program and access was denied to run that. I thought it was a gitosis thing but it wasn't.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can fix them retroactively (after which you won't need the config setting) with

```
chmod -R user:group /path/to/shared.git
find /path/to/shared.git -type d |xargs chmod 2775   # or 2770 if you don't want it public
find /path/to/shared.git -type f |xargs chmod 444    # or 440
find /path/to/shared.git/hooks   |xargs chmod ugo+x  # or ug+x
```

Comment: So the .git repo is hosted on my gitosis server (different box) which doesn't know about user1 or group dev. Those are just users and groups on the dev server (again not the server hosting gitosis)  So do I need to let gitosis know about the user on the other box?

Comment: I don't speak gitosis, I know that the commands I give here will work if it's not trying to get too cute.